# Can a car be "naked"?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, translation, italian

It's a rare event when I can't find the English equivalent for an Italian expression. It's even rarer when that Italian term consists of one word, but in English I have to build an entire phrase.

That's the case with the Italian verb *verniciare* which can be translated as "to varnish" or "to paint". But what about *[sverniciare](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sverniciare#Italian)*? A single word that means *to take off the paint* or *varnish* from something.

I am particularly interested in knowing if there is a one word equivalent for:

- to strip a car of its [paintwork](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paintwork)
- to strip the paintwork from a car

Do the above sound "natural"? I don't think anybody would be confused but perhaps there is some jargon or slang that is commonly used among car mechanics.

And after the paintwork has been stripped off, what is that car called? I keep thinking of *naked car*, *nude car* and even *raw car* but that can't be right.

So I would also like to know if there is a word, or short expression for:

- a car whose paintwork has been stripped

Comment: I've never heard of one, but your best bet would probably be to consult the owner of a body shop. My guess is that they would just call it by some phrasal name, however.

Comment: @Robusto I live in Italy, I don't know any mechanics who can speak English. :) I'm asking because I was helping a kid to translate his story into English.

Comment: A _bare-metal_ restoration involves stripping the vehicle of all it's coatings, but _bare-metal_ doesn't exclusively mean 'a car stripped of it's coatings'.

Comment: @Frank "bare metal" already sounds better, thanks!

Comment: Adding to Frank's suggestion:  *We took the car down to bare metal* https://www.google.com/search?q=%22down%20to%20bare%20metal%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Josh61 "unpainted car" suggests a car which has still to be painted, not *after* its paint has been stripped. But... I'm not 100% certain. I think the closest to "sverniciare" would be "to DISPAINT".

Comment: @TRomano (and Frank) So e.g. "...in the garage I saw the the bare metal car" and "It had been taken down to bare metal"?

Comment: Not quite no. _taken down to the bare-metal_ is OK. I would probably use _unprimed_ in your first sentence _...in the garage I saw the unprimed car_. Of course that doesn't make it clear it had previously been taken back to the bare-metal, because that info is not important.

Comment: I really don't think there is a single word that means _remove all the coatings from a car_ in English. _Stripped_ works for lots of things meaning _had the paint/varnish removed_ but _stripped_ for cars means _all ancillary parts have been removed_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Dispaint?..I think the best translation is to remove, or better, to strip paint from (a car):http://www.wikihow.com/Strip-Paint-From-Your-Car

Comment: @Josh61 in fact it doesn't exist, and it's not included in the question. But the prefix **dis-** would have fitted better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - as you correctly pointed out '
It's rare event when I can't find the English equivalent for an Italian expression'.

Comment: @Frank no, it's important the car was one colour and then its paint had been stripped. But I like *unprimed* and it could work, I'd forgotten about that word. When is someone going to post an answer? It doesn't have to be a single-word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Remember that compared to Continentals, the British are very coy about nakedness!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - how much simpler in Italian in this case: sverniciare una macchina, una macchina sverniciata!!

Comment: The problem is that any word you choose -- strip, denude, bare-metal, etc -- will have other (often unseemly) connotations.

Comment: Depaintified.  New word of the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single word, one could use *denude* and it's various forms.

> [OED] **denude**.
>   1. trans. To make naked or bare; to strip of clothing or covering; spec. in Geol. of natural agencies: To lay bare (a rock or formation) by the removal of that which lies above it.

However, if you were to take your car into a garage and ask them to *denude* it, I suspect they'd all glance at the Pirelli calendar hanging on the office wall before taking a deep breath in through their teeth and saying *Could be quite costly*.

Another possibility is *strip*

> [OED] **strip**
>   11. a. To remove (an adhering covering of skin, bark, lead, paper, etc.); to pull off (leaves, fruit) from a tree, etc.; to remove (paint or varnish) from woodwork, etc. Also to strip off. Cf. stripped ppl. a. b.

However, if you were to ask your local garage to *strip* your car, they would immediately set about removing any part of the car than can be removed, leaving you with a large pile of parts and a car body that is still completely covered in paint.

---

If we are not restricted to a single word then ***bare metalled*** seems to be term used occasionally in the body shop community.

The only term, that I'm aware of, that is used by body shop people for removing paint from a car is to *take it down/back to the bare-metal*. This usually involves sand blasting the coverings from the metal (glass beads these days for health and safety reasons). Some images can be found here http://the2cvshop.co.uk/shotblasting_1_classic.html

With thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet, it seems that *bare-metal* can be verbed into *bare metalled*.

> [SPR Coachworks Ltd] at https://www.facebook.com/SPRCoachworksLtd/posts/683435985028935
>   Porsche 356A has now been bare metalled.
>   We then applied an Epoxy coating to protect the bare metal from corroding.

and

> [DasRestohaus] at http://dasrestohaus.com.au/gallery2/v/Type+2/Jacks+59+11+window/Oct29+nose+bare+metalled.JPG.html
>   Oct29 nose bare metalled
>   The nose was taken back to bare metal to do some repairs (yep even new panels are not perfectly straight)....deoxidine applied first to condition metal

Once you have it at the bare-metal stage, the next stage is to *prime* it, so you could say that the car is *unprimed*.

> [OED] **priming**
>   4. concr. a. The substance or mixture used by painters for the preparatory coat. b. A coat or layer of the substance. Also fig.

---

Humorously (or humourlessly) you could perhaps coin *DeLoreanated* with reference to the DeLorean DMC-12 which has a completely unpainted body shell

Comment: Good answer...my only doubt is about 'unprimed car', an expression I cound not find in google.

Comment: @Josh61 It's probably a rare thing because in that state rust forms quickly, you might have more hits with _pre-primed chassis_ or _pre-primed monocoque_.

Comment: Having never had the, erm, fortune to set foot in a body workshop (or just a garage in general, really), I have no idea if this works … but could _bare-metal_ not quite easily be verbed? Instead of saying they took the car back/down to the bare-metal, could one not just say that they _bare-metalled the car_, and that the car was therefore then _a bare-metalled car_?

Comment: Maybe *[primed car](https://www.google.it/search?q=unprimed+vehicle&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=lIrsVNT0LNbkatytgsgM&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=primed+car&imgdii=_&imgrc=ChhPstxy2mRCvM%253A%3BAr26j5qgduxVfM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fforums.pelicanparts.com%252Fuploads15%252F035%252Bwhole%252Bcar%252Bprimed%252Band%252Bsanded1254614800.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fforums.pelicanparts.com%252Fpaint-bodywork-discussion-forum%252F502929-diy-iroc-rsr-conversion.html%3B800%3B600)* is better?

Comment: @Mari-LouA _primed_ means it has a coat of primer on the metal; to prevent rust and provide adhesion for the following coats.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _bare metalled_ is not a term I've personally heard (having spent too much time with old cars) but it seems it is in use - see https://www.facebook.com/SPRCoachworksLtd/posts/683435985028935 "Porsche 356A has now been bare metalled."

Comment: @Mary-LouA: You have to decide what you're trying to translate.  Do you want to describe the process of removing the paint? The car after its paint has been removed? You also have to consider the register of the original when deciding upon the choices presented here.

Comment: @TRomano both, the process and the adjective form. I'm happy with translating the Italian text as: "the car was reduced/stripped to its *bare metal* and *bare metalled*

Comment: We would not say "reduced". When a car is reduced to metal it is chopped up into small bits, and melted down.

Comment: You have a typo "it's"

Answer (score 3):

For a one-word-request I'd suggest "sanded", "sandblasted", or maybe "acid-dipped".

Comment: To *blast a car*, and *a sand blasted car* also work, don't they?

Comment: I don't know car-related terminology very well, nor what difference there may be between American and UK English. I think I'd prefer to say "took the paint off", "stripped the paint", "removed the paint", except that those wouldn't answer your 'single-word-request'.

Comment: I did ask: ".. **if** there is a one word equivalent", but expressions, idioms etc. are just as welcomed. Thank you for posting your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the original Italian sentence reads, or who is speaking: the proverbial little old lady who drives her car only to church on Sunday, a collector of rare automobiles, or a street punk who races his hotrod down near the river where the cops don't patrol very often.

*Bare-metalled* might be something a street punk, or someone who restores cars, or perhaps even the body-shop workers might say. It sounds like argot.

But in a neutral register, we'd say *The car was taken down to bare metal for a new coat of paint* and *I saw the car sitting in the body shop; it had been taken down to bare metal.*